# How to keep a copy of template view as it is before updating its field value in django?

Tags: python, django, date

I need to keep a copy of rendering all data of a view as it is, i.e. its first view.  When updated any value of the fields, its content will be changed. After updating, rendering the same template will give different data than first view. But I need to see the previous view or rendered data. For example:

[image]

[image]

You see in updated view of my sample there is some changes which is indicated as bold and italic. After updating I want to retrieve my original data as it is.

Is there any better way to do that?

Comment: How long do you want to be able to retrieve the original data? Because that may set some requirements whether you'll store it in the database (that'd be quite indefinitely), keep it in memory (possibly as long as your server is running, depending on how you've set things up), temporary for the user's convenience (as a cookie), etc.

Comment: It will also depend on whether the original data needs to be kept *per visitor*, or overall. If I view this on a different machine, and I make changes, what did I see originally, and what is to be kept there.

Comment: All in all though, have a look at [Django's sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/). Perhaps that can serve the purpose.

Comment: @Event, I want to keep it permanently because at any time it may need to retrieve and show the authority or customer what has its original version.

Comment: How are the original data entered? Are they there from the start of the project?

Comment: Yes, it is entered from start of the project using linked models. I need to keep both original and updated view

Comment: Perhaps you can do something with Django admin's `dumpdata` command? Save the initial data to JSON? Depending on how easily you need to be able to retrieve the original data.

Comment: If I save as dumpdata, when I load this in future my updated data will remain or revert to original?